# How can I open a local PDF file using a SwiftUI button?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, webview, swiftui

I want to display a local PDF file through a new view when I tap a button.
I tried doing that using a UIViewRepresentable WebView but it's not working (I have worked with WebView only through NavigationList).

I leave my code, but feel free to suggest better option if the WebView is not the most optimal.

**ButtonView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ResumeView: View {

    let sfSymbol: String
    let text: String

    let fileUrl = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Resume", ofType: "pdf")

    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
            .fill(Color.white)
            .frame(height: 50.0)
            .overlay(
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: sfSymbol)
                        .foregroundColor(.init(red: 0.20, green: 0.33, blue: 0.55, opacity: 1.00))
                    Button(action: {
                        WebView(urlString: self.fileUrl)
                    }) {
                    Text(text)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
            })
    }
}
```

**WebView**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import WebKit 

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {

    let urlString: String?

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<WebView>) {
        if let safeUrlString = urlString {
            if let url = URL(string: safeUrlString) {
                let request = URLRequest(url: url)
                uiView.load(request)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Slaine06, Apparently the answer to your question didn't work for you, but you managed to come up with a solution yourself (using sheets).  For those of us who are struggling with "How to open a local PDF file using a SwiftUI button?", would you be so kind as to share the code for your solution?  On StackOverflow, you are allowed to answer your own question - to provide help to future developers who are faced with the same question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using **`PDFKit`** we load local `PDF` file. Please try below code.

```
import SwiftUI
struct ResumeView: View {
    ....
    let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Resume", withExtension: "pdf")!
    var body: some View {
        ....
        Button(action: {
            PDFKitView(url: self.fileUrl)
        }) {
            Text(text)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
        ....
    }
}
```

**PDFKitView**

```
import PDFKit
struct PDFKitView: View {
    var url: URL
    var body: some View {
        PDFKitRepresentedView(url)
    }
}

struct PDFKitRepresentedView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    init(_ url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) -> PDFKitRepresentedView.UIViewType {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: self.url)
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        return pdfView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) {
        // Update the view.
    }
}
```

Comment: With only that code I didn't get any error but the view was not showing itself.
So I looked up way to show views in SwiftUI modally. And I solved using sheet.
Still it brought me to be able to solve my problem, thank you very much.

Comment: @Slaine06 can you provide how you solved this stuck in this issue no soln so far

Comment: @Slaine06 Can you please post your solution showing how you solved this. Apparently a large number of us are stuck with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For open pdf in app, you must do this:

```
struct PDFKitRepresentedView: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) -> PDFKitRepresentedView.UIViewType {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("earth.pdf"))
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        
        return pdfView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) {
        // EMPTY!
    }
}
```

And, in where use PDFKitRepresentedView(), example below

```
VStack {
    pdfView
    Button {} label: {Text("Test")}
}
```