# What will my PDF location be in local app files? - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, pdf, swiftui, pdfkit

I have sourced a function that converts a view to a PDF from  another stack overflow post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60753437/12969913. With this I am using another view to try and display the PDF inside a new view for the user to inevitably share and view as they wish.

How do I get my PDF to display, I can't figure out how the URL works and what I have to put into the new view.

The URL is created in the `exportToPDF()` function:

```
let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let outputFileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SwiftUI.pdf")
```

I have then sourced some code to display the PDF from another stack overflow post and have implemented that - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61480852/12969913, but in order for this to work I have to put in my file URL, how do I do that, and what will the file URL be?

My `PDFKitView()` Code - to display the new .pdf:

```
struct PDFKitView: View {
    var url: URL
    var body: some View {
        PDFKitRepresentedView(url)
    }
}

struct PDFKitRepresentedView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    init(_ url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) -> PDFKitRepresentedView.UIViewType {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: self.url)
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        return pdfView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) {
        // Update the view.
    }
}
```

I then go to display this using:

```
HStack{
    PDFKitView(url: ????????)
    Text("Hello World")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are droping the PDF file directly to your Xcode project, this is how you will be able to retrive the URL:

```swift
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "SwiftUI", ofType: "pdf") else { return }
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
```

Comment: I couldn't get the guard to work and instead used the same variables to find my pdf as I did to set the location

Comment: I have used guard to safely unwrap the optional value, you can skip it if you want to. Just be careful with force unwrapping (`!`) the path value.

Comment: So did the `Bundle.main.path` help you find the PDF file?

Comment: I didn't use that in the end, I used `let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SwiftUI.pdf")`